# How can I convert timestamp strings in R to a number that I can do calculations with?

Tags: r

So I currently read in a .cvs file (as a dataframe ndata) that contains timestamp strings that are in a format like the following:

```
year-month-day hour:minute:second,millisecond
Example: "2016-08-26 19:06:11,380"
```

I contain the values of the timestamp in ndata$time.
I tried using

```
ndata$modifiedTime = as.numeric(ndata$time)
```

But this didn't work because R didn't acknowledge the timestamp as a timestamp but rather as any other string. Is there a way that I can alter/redefine the timestamp string so that I can store these values as a set amount of seconds after time 0 (0000-00-00 00:00:00,000) and actually use these dates in calculations?

Comment: R has builtin data-types that handle dates and times. Try the `lubridate` package for easy ways to work with them: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to R date-time using `as.POSIXct` or other methods and then use `as.numeric`. For manipulating time you can use `lubridate` which is quite useful:

```
tstamp <- "2016-08-26 19:06:11,380"

z <- (as.POSIXct(tstamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC"))

> as.numeric(z)
[1] 1472238371
```

Comment: This drops the 380.

Answer (score 2):

Below we input a string `s` and then convert it to a POSIXct object `p` and then a number `num` representing the number of seconds since the Epoch (January 1, 1970).

We then reverse the process, creating a POSIXct object `p2` and then formatting that back into a string `s2`.

We see that the original string `s` and the string obtained from `num` are identical.

No packages are used.

```
s <- "2016-08-26 19:06:11,380" # test input

# convert string to numeric
p <- as.POSIXct(chartr(",", ".", s))
num <- as.numeric(p)

# convert numeric to string
p2 <- as.POSIXct(num, origin = "1970-01-01")
s2 <- chartr(".", ",", format(p, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3"))

identical(s, s2)
## [1] TRUE
```